# Link PS3 Diablo 3 character with battlenet/Diablo 3 forum?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I purchased Diablo 3 for PS3 as a pre-order download. I don't own any other copies of D3 on any other platforms. I would like to post comments on the D3 forums, but it states: "You need a character (created in-game) to post on the forums." on the create topic button. I've looked for a game key in the PSN network confirmation email of my purchase, in the various menus in the game, the account management screens on PS3, and in the store under downloads... nowhere to be found. I'm probably going about this all wrong, but I just want to link my character my online [Diablo III forum account](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/9582320/). I did use the same email address as my PSN account when I created my account, and that didn't "automatically" link them... maybe this isn't possible with the PS3 version?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken at look at battle.net to see if there is any indication that you have a key pre-associated with your [account](http://battle.net)? Sadly I poked around and couldn't find anything myself BUT I also do not own the game. "If you received a digital product as a gift, the code is located inside the gift email. Alternately, you can click on the link in the email to claim the game key." Is all that battle.net gives me.

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ over on Blizzard's [official console](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/console/) site states the following:

1. A Battle.net account isn't required to play the game on consoles.
2. There are currently no plans for connectivity between Battle.net and PSN or Xbox Live.

This means that the characters on your Battle.net account and PlayStation account will remain separate. If you don't have the PC version, you're out of luck.

Besides, someone already contacted Battle.net support regarding this issue and it looks like it's [here to stay](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Technical-Help/Why-can-t-PlayStation-3-players-post-on-the-official-Blizzard/td-p/19681534), even though the forum titled "Console" is misleading. According to Blizzard, it's basically for owners of both the console and PC versions.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the detailed answer. On a side note, I flipp'n love this game. I know a lot of people the play DIII on PC, and say it's a lot more fun on the console ... obviously an opinion ... (it's like it was made for console), so I'm not sure why they (e.g. battle.net, blizzard) wouldn't embrace that in their forum interactions as well. I would love to see this game go cross platform (meaning multiple platforms playing online together), but if they are keeping the forums separate like that, there's no way the game will ever not be separate.

Comment: It was made for consoles...hence the console games.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are bothered about is being able to post in the forum - you can download the starter addition of D3 (basically a demo) that will enable you to post as a user.

That's the way I do it at present.

Comment: I've heard the PS4 version is going to be linked to Battle.net ... I wonder if this will fix the issue? Thoughts?